# Solving a cyclic include dependency in Julia

Tags: julia

Suppose the following (it is supposed to be like a typical Julia package):

###### pkg.jl

```
module pkg
    include("a.jl")
    include("b.jl")
end  # module
```

###### a.jl

```
struct A
    a
end  # struct

function use_B(obj::B)
    return obj.b
end  # function
```

###### b.jl

```
struct B
    b
end  # struct

function use_A(obj::A)
    return obj.a
end  # function
```

Notice that `pkg.jl` imports `a.jl` first. If I run the file, it gives me an `UndefVarError` because the `use_B()` function in `a.jl` doesn't know what `B` is.

If I import `b.jl` first in `pkg.jl`, it also gives me an `UndefVarError`, now because the `use_A()` function in `b.jl` doesn't know what `A` is.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

---

P.S. I would like to know a solution that does not require me to move `use_A()` or `use_B()` to a different file.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would put definitions of `A` and `B` structs in a separate file called, for example, typedefs.jl, that is included as first in your pkg.jl file. You can see how it is achieved for example here https://github.com/JuliaData/CategoricalArrays.jl/tree/master/src.